# Getting the count of a column from a set of comma separated values?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns and I want to get a list of unique Places with the a sum of the Count from the next column.

For example:

**Current**

```
Places (ColumnA)                  Count(ColumnB)
Italy, Greece, France             10
Italy, Greece                     5
France                            1
```

**Desired outcome**

```
Places (ColumnD)                  Count(ColumnE)
Italy                             15
Greece                            15
France                            11
```

Comment: I don't need the headers but yes I am looking for ColumnD too. I just used that as an identifier to show that the results were displayed in another column. I have comma delimited values in a column and then a value of the amount of times that pattern was used but I want to end up with something like the desired outcome where all unique Places are in one column and the sum of all the counts that contained that place in the next column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in row 2, try in D2:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(trim(transpose(split(concatenate(A2:A&","),",")))),sumif(A2:A, "=*"&unique(trim(transpose(split(concatenate(A2:A&","),","))))&"*",B2:B)})
```

or, alternatively:

```
=query(ArrayFormula({transpose(split(query(substitute(A2:A,",",""),,50000)," ")),transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B&char(9), len(A2:A)-len(substitute(A2:A, ",",""))+1 )),char(9)))}), "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'' ")
```

Yet another way (credits to AdamL for this one):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(A2:A&", ",B2:B),,ROWS(A2:A)),", "))&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))
```

Comment: @pnuts.. correct ! I added an alternative... just in case ! :-) And if both won't work we can maybe work out something else..

Comment: In most situations there is more than one good answer. I used open ranges because I can imagine the data given is just a small sample of the actual data. I also assume most people know how they can  'limit' that range by providing an end row (at least I hope so)... As you surely have noticed, there are actually two formula's kept together with a literal array.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I got the first function to work perfectly. The second function ended up with a #Value error saying that "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNCol2" in which I am still trying to get working. Also the sumproduct seems to work just as well for the sum of all the values.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. My standard practice is to use `ROWS(A2:A)` rather than `50000` to cover this possibility.

Comment: Another QUERY-based option (I would rather leave it as a comment or JPV can edit it in as third option, as opposed to a new answer): `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(A2:A&", ",B2:B),,ROWS(A2:A)),", "))&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))`

Comment: @AdamL: great alternative ! I've added it to the answer.